# return value from one function to other

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im using the following code and my question is how should I pass the port from the first function to the seconde,I know that if I call to second function **inside** the first I can do that but there is other way which is good parctise to use?

```
 portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 3010, '127.0.0.1', function(error, port) {
        console.log('AVAILABLE PORT AT: ' + port)
    });

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
   JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
        res.end();
    }).listen(9033);
```

instead of using port 9033 I want to use the value from the first...

Comment: Move the bottom statement into the callback function of `portscanner.findAPortNotInUse()`.

Comment: *"but there is other way which is good parctise to use"* nope.

Comment: If you're going to use NodeJS, you're just going to have to get used to callback craziness, otherwise switch to a different language that has modern facilities for concurrent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port scanner method is *asynchronous*, so the only way is to create the server when the available port has been determined, when your callback function is called:

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 3010, '127.0.0.1', function(error, port) {
    console.log('AVAILABLE PORT AT: ' + port)
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      // ...
    }).listen(port);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jack but as I write :) I know that if I call the create server inside I will able to do that but my question iff there is other way to do so...,Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right, and I'm telling you that's the only way ;-)

Comment: Thanks Jack, I try it but somehow if I put console log inside the create server I dont see the message,any idea why?

Comment: @AlBundy If you put the console.log() inside the createServer, it will only run when there's a request.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with async code. Try

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 3010, '127.0.0.1', function(error, port) {
    console.log('AVAILABLE PORT AT: ' + port);

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
        res.end();
    }).listen(port);

});
```

---

If you don't want to run the `createServer` portion within the callback, another option is to make it a function call. This doesn't really do anything other than change the syntax though

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 3010, '127.0.0.1', function(error, port) {
    console.log('AVAILABLE PORT AT: ' + port);

    // call the 'CreateServer' function with the available port
    CreateServer(port);
});

function CreateServer (port) {
     http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
        res.end();
    }).listen(port);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried the second option but it seems that nothing happen if I put console log inside the create server,any idea why?

Comment: @AlBundy is your other `console.log('Available port at....')` line printing? There's no real difference between the 2 options (I had a typo, but I've fixed it)

Answer (score 1):

```
function start(callback){
    portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(3000, 3010, '127.0.0.1', function(error, port) {
        console.log('AVAILABLE PORT AT: ' + port)
        callback(port);
    });
}

start(function(){
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
        res.end();
    }).listen(port);
})
```

try this code.

Comment: Care to elaborate why this is "good practice"? Simply giving someone who wants to learn a piece of code is not very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

What kind of type does the first method return? You can simple make it a String and set the result of it to a private String variable which will be defined in the class. Then you simply want to do this:

**listen(this.port);**

Alternatively, you can set a **final static String** variable port which will pass to both methods as a parameter.